# Página de pesquisa com o "motivo" de fechamento em inglês

Tags: bug, tradução

Ao fazer uma pesquisa qualquer, quando é retornado uma pergunta fechada os motivos aparecem em inglês, um exemplo com todas perguntas fechadas do site que ainda estão publicas:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3Ayes

Vejam que retorna isto:

> [image: motivos de fechamentos na pagina de busca]

Ao entrar nas perguntas esta em **português**:

> [image: pergunta 1]
>
> [image: pergunta 2]